# Exception thrown when executing model rule for augmented reality app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am working on the [ARSimple](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_examples) example for ARToolKit and after setting my SDK to 4.4 and using my real device (yes I enabled USB debugging) I get this error when trying to run. What is causing this error? I can provide more info as needed.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':aRSimple'.

> Exception thrown while executing model rule: com.android.build.gradle.model.BaseComponentModelPlugin$Rules#createAndroidComponents(org.gradle.platform.base.ComponentSpecContainer,
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistry,
com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig, 
com.android.build.gradle.AndroidConfig, 
org.gradle.model.ModelMap<com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType>, 
org.gradle.model.ModelMap<com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor>, 
org.gradle.model.ModelMap<com.android.build.gradle.managed.SigningConfig>,
com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.VariantFactory, 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager, org.gradle.api.Project,
com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder, 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler, 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.ExtraModelInfo,
java.lang.Boolean)

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Comment: Check the SDK Manager and make sure you have downloaded API 23.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you do not have API 23 installed. You need to start the SDK Manager and download it.

Alternatively, you can set `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file to the API version you wish to use instead.